# How to adjusts variables in coxph (R)?

Tags: r, variables, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am very confused about how to adjust variables in the coxph function. I know one can do stratification with strata(), but how about adjust for variables?

In the linear model, one can adjust the variables by the following

(here's one example I saw from this [link](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~gary/classes/5303/handouts/covariates.pdf))

```
fit.diamOnMachine <- lm(diameter˜machine)
diam.adjusted <- residuals(fit.diamOnMachine)
fit.diamadjmach <- lm(strength ˜ diam.adjusted + machine)
```

In coxph, does one do the same thing? For example, I have age, gender, BMI, time to event, outcome and a list of protein expression values of 1000 individuals.

I'd like to know how to adjust age, gender and BMI in the following coxph model:

```
coxph(Surv(Time_till_event, outcome) ~ protein_expression_values, data = data)
```

Should I just add the variables that I need to adjust into the equation like this:

```
coxph(Surv(Time_till_event, outcome) ~ protein_expression_values + age + gender + BMI, data = data)
```

I have been through a lot of material on the internet but I don't seem to be able to find appropriate answers. I have never taken linear regression classes and just started reading/learning it online. If you have recommended material, I would highly appreciate it too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your core objective is to model survival time as a function of protein expression values, but that you also want to control for variables which might confound this relationship (i.e., age, gender, BMI). If so, just include all these terms in your formula as you suggest above (i.e.,  `protein_expression_values + age + gender + BMI`). The protein expression coefficient(s) output from the model will then represent the effect of expression on survival for a given age, gender and BMI.

As a disclaimer, I've never seen anyone do the adjustment you link in your question, so it's possible that I misunderstand your objective.